# How can I remove NULL values from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I made a function in `R` which accepts a string and outputs patterns in it. For example, for the string, `"abcabcabc"`, it outputs `"abc"` but if I have the string as, `"abcdefghi"`, it outputs, `" "`. Now, on running this function over a `dataframe` containing 1000's of rows, I obtained the output, but the output `dataframe`consists of several rows having `" "` this as the output. How can I remove this?
The output dataframe is of the following type:

```
1 2 abc
2 3 bc
3 4 t
4 5 " "
5 3 ui
```

So, I want to remove the row containing values in the first two columns as 4 and 5. 
Thanks!

Comment: I have the former case. And I will add a small example of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is not `NULL` (try `is.null(" ")`). What you're seeing is a factor level `" "` (nothing between the quotes). You can remove rows of a data.frame by searching for this string.

```
xy[!xy$col %in% " ", ] # I added ! to actually select the inverse, as advertized
```

or if appropriate, you can merge it to some other factor level by redefining `levels(xy)`.

Here's an example

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- data.frame(first = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", " ", " ", " ", "d", "d"), 
                 second = runif(10))

xy[!xy$first %in% " ", ] # can select multiple values (see below)
xy[!xy$first == " ", ] # alternative, can select only one value

# bonus
xy[!xy$first %in% c("a", " "), ]
```

Comment: I did this, but on running this command, it outputs, `[1] X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` where my dataframe consists of 23k rows.

Comment: @Elliot I've misread your values. It should be `" "` (one space between quotes). See my edit.